# backbone.js fetch page once

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

Im creating a single page scrolling site. Which means all the data from json is loaded at once and there is no need to fetch data multiple times every time the hash changes.

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
routes: {
    ""          : "index",
    ":page" : "page"
},

index: function() {
    console.log('list');
    this.init = new WH.ExperienceCollection();
    this.book = new WH.ExperienceBook({model: this.init});
    this.init.fetch();
},

page: function(page) {
    this.init = new WH.ExperienceCollection();
    this.book = new WH.ExperienceBook({model: this.init});
    this.init.fetch({success: function(data){
        WH.utils.resize();
        $('html,body').stop(true, true).animate({scrollTop: $('#'+page).offset().top}, 500);
    }});
}
```

});

is my route. When the hash changes I want it to scroll down to that section. Right now the page keeps on fetching and adding on to whats already on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should store in a variable if the collection has been fetched or not. And then, depending on this variable, refetch or not.

For example:

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

    init: new WH.ExperienceCollection(),
    book: new WH.ExperienceBook({model: this.init}),
    fetched: false,

    routes: {
        ""          : "index",
        ":page" : "page"
    },

    index: function() {
        console.log('list');
        this.init = new WH.ExperienceCollection();
        this.book = new WH.ExperienceBook({model: this.init});
        this.init.fetch();
    },

    page: function(page) {
        var self = this;
        if( this.fetched ) {
            render();
        } else {
         this.init.fetch({success: render});
        }

        function render(){
            self.fetched = true;
            Westin.utils.resize();
            $('html,body').stop(true, true).animate({scrollTop: $('#'+page).offset().top}, 500);
        }
    }
});
```

*There's probably other solution depending on what's inside your collection. But as a global answer, this is the most general case. But for example, you could also test a collection length to see if it is filled up or not, or check if a value in present on a model, etc, etc. The idea is to have something telling you if the collection/model is fetched or not.*

Answer (score 1):

If it's needed for every route (or many of them), then [put it in the Router's `initialize` function](http://jsfiddle.net/j2mF4/3/):

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        if (!this.init) {
            console.log("fetching init...");
            this.init = WH.ExperienceCollection();
            this.book = new WH.ExperienceBook({ model: this.init });
            this.init.fetch();
        } else {
            console.log("init already fetched!");
        }
    },
});
```

This will run once when the page is first loaded.